# How to let typescript know a class property is definitely initialized when it's set via a Promise constructor?

Tags: typescript

I have this very simple class definition

```
class Container {
    resolveData: (s: string) => void // not definitely initialized error!
    data: Promise<string>
    constructor() {
        this.data = new Promise<string>(
            r => this.resolveData = r
        )
    }
}
```

where typescript complains that the `resolveData` property is not definitely initialized.

I think the reason is that typescript doesn't know the callback is synchronously executed. How do I let typescript know that the property is definitely initialized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stick an `!` next to the property definition to assert to typescript that you know that the property is definitely initialized

```
class Container {
    resolveData!: (s: string) => void 
    data: Promise<string>
    constructor() {
        this.data = new Promise<string>(
            r => this.resolveData = r
        )
    }
}
```

As with all type assertions, this is a way to tell typescript "i know more than you do, so don't check my work here". Your example seems like a case where it's correct to use this, but if you use the assertion when in fact it's not being initialized correctly, typescript won't be able to point that out to you.

If you want to search for more on this piece of syntax, it's referred to as the "Definite Assignment Assertion"

Comment: @VLAZ why would it fail?

Comment: @hgl wait...I think I've actually misread the code. Yeah, sorry, you're right this works.